# How to use RiccatiSolve with symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic, control-systems

According to the `RiccatiSolve` [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiccatiSolve.html) the `Eigensystem` method can apply to symbolic matrices. 
However, I can not get it to work, here is what I have tried so far:

```
$Assumptions = m ∈ Matrices[{2, 2}];

RiccatiSolve[{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, m}, {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, Method -> "Eigensystem"]

RiccatiSolve::matrix: Argument m at position {1, 2} is not a non-empty rectangular matrix.
```

```
RiccatiSolve[{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, a}}}, {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, Method -> "Eigensystem"]
RiccatiSolve::nonnum: RiccatiSolve has received a matrix with non-numerical elements.
```

Can anyone tell me how to use a symbolic matrix with `RiccatiSolve` and what a symbolic matrix is.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: If you check the documentation the second argument of 'RiccatiSolve' should be a column vector? Perhaps start with the example in the documentation.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken, the second argument can also be a matrix. E.g. `RiccatiSolve[{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, Method -> "Eigensystem"]` works fine.

Comment: I do not expect your first one to work, but your second one is supposed to. I would inform Support about this.

Comment: @NeonNuke, yes sorry you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`RiccatiSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiccatiSolve.html) and [`DiscreteRiccatiSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteRiccatiSolve.html) can handle symbolic matrices as long as the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian are numeric so that the solver can determine those on the left- and right-half planes.

In this case

```
aa = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
bb = {{1, 0}, {0, a}};
qq = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
rr = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
```

and the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian matrix are

```
ArrayFlatten[{{aa, -bb.Inverse[rr].Transpose[bb]}, {-qq, -Transpose[aa]}}];
Eigenvalues[%]
```

> $\{-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{a^2+1},\sqrt{a^2+1}\}$

Unless $a$ is real, those eigenvalues will be on the imaginary axis.

The documentation in 12.1, and probably earlier, is not accurate and will need to be fixed.